# How can I make my python code accept keyboard input?

Tags: python, input, interface, keyboard

For example, if the program asks the user to press enter on their keyboard to continue, the program can recognise it & continue. I'm still a student so not really sure, is it possible..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`input`](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html#the-input-function) command

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `input` statement and assign the input to variables like this:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("Hello there, " + name + "!")
```

It's that simple!

Answer (score 0):

Use the input function as well as if statements:

```
x = input("What's 1+1?")
if x == 2:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```